# Ember StateManager not reflecting currentState accurately

Tags: javascript, ember.js, state-machine

I'm starting to build a very basic Ember.StateManager and having a problem with obtaining an accurate currentState. My understanding is that by the time a state's enter callback is run, `currentState.name` should reflect this new state.

I'm using ember-1.0.0-pre.2.min.js

Here's my problem:

```
My.Tabs = {
  init: function() {
    MY.Tabs.stateManager.transitionTo('about');

    // this logs 'about' which is correct
    console.log(this.stateManager.get('currentState.name'));
  },

  stateManager: Em.StateManager.create({
    enableLogging: true,
    start: Em.State.create({
      exit: function(stateManager) {
        // this logs 'start'
        console.log(stateManager.get('currentState.name');
      }
    }),
    about: Em.State.create({
      enter: function(stateManager) {
        // ###### HERE's THE PROBLEM ######
        // this logs 'start'...at this point shouldn't this be 'about'?
        // since I'm already in the enter callback?
        console.log(stateManager.get('currentState.name');
      },
      exit: function(stateManager) {
        return console.log("On about exit");
      }
   })
  })
};
```

As you can see, when I call `transitionTo('about')` and that state's `enter` callback is run, `currentState.name` still reflects the original state, `start`.

It's only after my `transitionTo('about')` that `currentState.name` is accurate.

Are my expectations wrong, or am I doing something wrong?

The documentation states:

> After transitioning into a new state the new currentState will have its enter method called with the StateManager instance as its first argument and an object representing the transition as its second argument.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Looking at the source on github](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-pre.2/packages/ember-states/lib/state_manager.js#L891) I see

```
enterState: function(transition) {
    var log = this.enableLogging;

    var exitStates = transition.exitStates.slice(0).reverse();
    arrayForEach.call(exitStates, function(state) {
      state.trigger('exit', this);
    }, this);

    arrayForEach.call(transition.enterStates, function(state) {
      if (log) { Ember.Logger.log("STATEMANAGER: Entering " + get(state, 'path')); }
      state.trigger('enter', this);
    }, this);

    set(this, 'currentState', transition.finalState);
  }
```

clearly, the `currentState` is set AFTER the enter method is called, which would explain what you are seeing.

You can confirm by getting the current state name in your console after the transition.

Comment: that was my next step, to check the source code. thanks for your quick response! I feel like the documentation is a little misleading because they make it sound like by the time you're in `enter` `currentState` has already changed. anyways, there's also a `setup` callback which gets called after `enter` and has the new state name.

Comment: @djibouti33 Please do submit a pull request for doc changes if you can improve them.